# Объединение двух полей разных форматов в одну строку в запросе

Tags: visual-basic, sql

Не могу запустить запрос в SQL в Visul Basic 6, там в форме нужно вывести одно поле с значениями `номер_дома`(числовой) и через пробел `литера_дома`(строковое). Пишу запрос к базе типа:

```
select num_house & '' & sim_house
```

Answer (score 1):

если у вас используется SQL Server то конкатенация осуществляется оператором "+" и запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
SELECT (CAST(num_house AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' ' + sim_house) as adress
```